# lithium-ion and liiion tags

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-cleanup, tag-synonyms, retagging

I noticed there is a [lithium-ion](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/lithium-ion) tag with over 1K questions and a [liion](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/liion) tag with 39 questions.

I'm thinking that perhaps most (or all) of the [liion](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/liion) questions could be retagged with [lithium-ion](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/lithium-ion) and that those two tags could be synonymized.

What do you think?

Comment: We can just replace liion with lithium-ion. I see no reason to preserve the former.

Comment: @Lundin The reason to preserve the former is the same reason we have a [li-ion] tag (which is synonymized with the [lithium-ion] tag).  By creating a synonym, it prevents the unwanted tag from getting recreated over and over again and people tagging their questions with it.

Comment: It is possible to blacklist tags so that they can never get re-created.

Comment: @Lundin I'm not sure of the pros/cons of using synonyms vs. banning a tag.  Maybe someone knows.  I've always seen synonyms used, but it's very likely that is reflective of observation bias, as I don't think I would know that a tag that is banned, but I do see synonyms.

Comment: It is much easier to make a synonym, I think that is the best course of action. A synonym replaces the tag, however, blacklisting blocks and does not provide an alternative.

Comment: @VoltageSpike That makes good sense. Thanks!

Comment: I volunteer to replace all the "liion" tags with the "lithium-ion" tag.